Why does the USB-C give 9V instead of 5V
I recently received my custom-built PCB, which is powered through USB-C. Upon plugging it in, there was smoke! My design includes 5.1 kOhm pull-down resistors on both CC1 and CC2 pins, which I thought would ensure a default 5V supply. My understanding is that USB-C should default to 5V unless a higher voltage is negotiated digitally.
To troubleshoot, I tested my USB-C setup using an Adafruit USB-C breakout board (https://www.adafruit.com/product/4090) with identical 5.1 kOhm pull-downs on CC1 and CC2. I encountered the same result—9V instead of 5V!


Here's the setup I tested:
PCB with 5.1 kOhm pull-down resistors on CC1 and CC2: Resulted in 9V, with smoke on the PCB.
USB-C breakout board (Adafruit) with the same 5.1 kOhm configuration: Also shows 9V.
For reference, when I connect my PCB/breakout to an older USB-C port from my computer, I get the expected 5V.
The issue seems to be specifically with mobile fast chargers, which my product users are likely to use as well. I can't risk having the device burn if they plug it into a fast charger.
Why is the fast charger outputting 9V instead of the expected 5V with 5.1 kOhm pull-downs?
Is there a way to ensure my PCB always receives 5V, regardless of the charger used, without triggering higher voltages?

It's most likely unrelated to your problem but please learn how to clean your PCBs! This is a bit too crummy and could cause problems in analog or low-power digital circuits. Isopropyl alcohol and a stiff ESD brush does wonders.

You haven't told us anything about, or shown us, the charger. The resistors should configure PD for 5V / 1.5A, even on the Adafruit board. The problem must be the charger...

Well the charger is a USB-C charger that I got with my Samsung Galaxy S21 Ultra.  You mean that there is something wrong with my charger? I cannot have my future customers plug in their phone chargers and breaking the board. I must have missed something about conditions when it comes to 5V output.

Maybe Samsung cheaped out, and basically made a 9V wall-wart, with no PD negotiation. Technically then they shouldn't call it USB-C, but I wouldn't put it past them to save a couple of bucks on each unit. I'm curious to know what it says under "output" written on the charger itself.

@SimonFitch Model: C59
Input: AC 100.240V
Output: DC5V, 3A/9V 2,22A/12V
Made in China

Did you try to check VBUS voltage if no 5.1k pulldown resistors are present?
